# mutate across multiple column contain specific string with multiple column under condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data like below

```
> data
group  A_time1   A_time2   B_time1   B_time2   Z_time1   Z_time2
    1    12:03     11:05     02:07     08:51     18:28     09:45
    2    07:09     11:22     14:23     18:27     04:33     14:45
    3    11:22     07:22     18:09     21:36     14:38     12:21
    4    08:23     02:04     04:11     09:01     03:44     21:07
    5    01:15     07:19     05:27     13:32     14:01     15:02
```

I want multiple new column time_range with which time is early put the first position at once.

I tried code below

```
data %>% mutate(A_time_range = ifelse(as.numeric(gsub(":","",time1)) < as.numeric(gsub(":","",time2)),paste0(time1,"-",time2),paste0(time2,"-",time1)))


data %>% mutate_at(vars(contain("_time")), funs(. = ifelse(as.numeric(gsub(":","",.)) < as.numeric(gsub(":","",.)), ,paste0(time1,"-",time2),paste0(time2,"-",time1)),.names = '{col}_time_range')
```

Desired Output

```
group  A_time1   A_time2   A_time_range   A_grade B_time1   B_time2   B_time_range  B_grade  Z_time1   Z_time2  
    1    15:03     11:05    11:05-15:03       B     02:07     08:51    02:07-08:51      A      18:28     09:45
    2    07:09     11:32    07:09-11:32       A     14:23     18:27    14:23-18:27      B      04:33     14:45
    3    12:22     07:22    07:22-12:22       B+    18:09     21:36    18:09-21:36      A      14:38     12:21
    4    18:23     02:49    02:49-18:23       A-    04:11     09:01    04:11-09:01      A+     03:44     21:07
    5    01:15     07:19    01:15-07:19       B     15:27     13:32    13:32-15:27      A      14:01     15:02
```

How can I achieve this in R? Thanks.

Comment: You should handle time and date as such. It is rarely helpful to convert to string. You can check the `lubridate`  package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could pivot, sort, concatenate, and pivot back.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # >= version 1.1.0
              
df |>
  pivot_longer(-group, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("name", ".value")) |>
  mutate(time_range = paste0(sort(c(time1, time2)), collapse = "-"), .by = c(group, name)) |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "group",
              values_from = contains("time"),
              names_from = "name",
              names_glue = "{name}_{.value}",
              names_vary = "slowest")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 10
  group A_time1 A_time2 A_time_range B_time1 B_time2 B_time_range Z_time1 Z_time2 Z_time_range
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       
1 1     12:03   11:05   11:05-12:03  02:07   08:51   02:07-08:51  18:28   09:45   09:45-18:28 
2 2     07:09   11:22   07:09-11:22  14:23   18:27   14:23-18:27  04:33   14:45   04:33-14:45 
3 3     11:22   07:22   07:22-11:22  18:09   21:36   18:09-21:36  14:38   12:21   12:21-14:38 
4 4     08:23   02:04   02:04-08:23  04:11   09:01   04:11-09:01  03:44   21:07   03:44-21:07 
5 5     01:15   07:19   01:15-07:19  05:27   13:32   05:27-13:32  14:01   15:02   14:01-15:02
```

I would imagine that you want to use the `time`/`hm`-class instead of strings, and this approach should work there as well. However, it might need extra formatting.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer. I try the code at my data, got Caused by error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = c(group, name)`.
✖ `..1` must be size 3063024 or 1, not 6126048.
I'm not sure why will get this question.

Comment: Hello! I guess youll want to upgrade your dplyr version to 1.1.0